# Jupiter Script file Path

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Let say I am working on a python scrip repl mode in a notebook. And the file path is

> a/b/c/d/myscript.ipynb

What command should I issue that returns this path? I tried:

```
import os
!pwd
os.getcwd()
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

None of these return the file path to the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CS